# Calculate the start and end date of a week given the week number and year in C# (based on the ISO specification)

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetime, vb6, calendar

I need to generate a report that shows the 52 weeks of a year (or 53 weeks as some years have) and their start and end dates. There is an ISO spec to do this but seems awfully complicated! Im hoping someone knows of a way to do it in C# or Visual Basic (its actually for Visual Basic 6 but I will try port it across)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Calendar.GetWeekOfYear` method to get the week number of a date, with the `CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek` value to specify how the weeks are determined, and `DayOfWeek.Monday` to specify the first weekday. That follows the ISO specification.

Example:

```
int week = Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Today, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

To get the first date of the first week of the year, you can start from the 4th of january and go back until you find the monday:

```
DateTime t = new DateTime(DateTime.Today,Year, 1, 4);
while (t.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday) t = t.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: +1 Looks like the best solution - it's in Visual Basic as @Jimbo requires. I think it's going to be useful in my scenario ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741424/looking-for-definitive-iso-week-calculator-in-visual-basic-in-visual-studio-exp ) as well.

Comment: What do I use to Import the Calendar library? By default, Calendar is not defined so I need to Import it from somewhere, but where?

Comment: @therobyouknow: If you check the reference for the Calendar class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.aspx you see that it's in the `System.Globalization` namespace, so that's the namespace that you need to import. As it's in the `mscorlib.dll` assembly, you don't have to add any reference.

Comment: +1 Thanks @Guffa, I found this myself too. So to use the solution, I would 1) instantiate a instance of a concrete class inheriting from the abstract Calendar class, e.g.: `GregorianCalendar` as it is the de-facto standard: `Dim myCalendar As Calendar = New GregorianCalendar` and then 2) Use the instance `Dim week As Integer = myCalendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Today, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday)`

Comment: @therobyouknow: Yes, that looks right. I remembered the method to be static, but checking the reference I see that it isn't.

Comment: What is the reason for starting/going back from 4th Jan? What is significance of 4th Jan?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it manually, have a look at [this post](http://www.boyet.com/Articles/PublishedArticles/CalculatingtheISOweeknumb.html).

Comment: +1 I lifted that code and made it return a tuple for the iso week

Comment: Urgh, that's actually the nasty bit of that code. Even if you for some reason wanted to return it as a single primitive type (bad idea imo), then you should use binary `&` and shift right operations rather than division and modulo.

Answer (score 2):

This should work. I've used it on reporting in the past. I agree that it's not very pretty though:

```
DateTime GetWeekStartDate(int year, int week)
{
    DateTime jan1 = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    int day = (int)jan1.DayOfWeek - 1;
    int delta = (day < 4 ? -day : 7 - day) + 7 * (week - 1);

    return jan1.AddDays(delta);
}
```

That calculates the start date for a certain week. The end DateTime is obviously 7 days later (exclusive).

You may find [this code of mine](http://www.subbot.net/personal/external/stackoverflow/WeekAndYear.cs.txt) useful. It's barely documented, but it implements a few other operations on the WeekAndYear struct it defines. Plenty of room for improvement. Most notably, it defines `<` and `>` operators, but no others, which is pretty bad... but it should get you started.

Porting to VB6 though... Hmm, maybe not :P

Answer (score 2):

These functions covered my requirements (adapted for ASP Classic, hence to data types)
Hope they help others too...

```
Function WeekNumber(dDate)
    Dim d2
    d2 = DateSerial(Year(dDate - WeekDay(dDate - 1) + 4), 1, 3)
    WeekNumber = Int((dDate - d2 + WeekDay(d2) + 5) / 7)
End Function

Function YearStart(iWhichYear)
    Dim iWeekDay
    Dim iNewYear
    iNewYear = DateSerial(iWhichYear, 1, 1)
    iWeekDay = (iNewYear - 2) Mod 7
    If iWeekDay < 4 Then
        YearStart = iNewYear - iWeekDay
    Else
        YearStart = iNewYear - iWeekDay + 7
    End If
End Function

Function WeeksInYear(iYear)
    WeeksInYear = WeekNumber(DateAdd("d", -1, YearStart(iYear + 1)))
End Function

Function WeekStart(iYear, iWeek)
    WeekStart = DateAdd("ww", iWeek - 1, YearStart(iYear))
End Function

Function WeekEnd(iYear, iWeek)
    WeekEnd = DateAdd("d", 6, DateAdd("ww", iWeek - 1, YearStart(iYear)))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

use the [Calendar.GetWeekOfYear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear(VS.80).aspx) method to get the week of the current datetime, the rest should be trivial.

For vb6 it's less trivial, you're best bet is to find a good library which does the hard work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the start of the current week

```
dateAdd(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (Now.Day * -1), Now)
```

To get the end of the week add 7 days to the start of the week

Answer (score 0):

[System.Globalization.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is the following and is the most understandable

```html
 '1 declaramos las variables 
 Public firstdayweek As Date 'variable para capturar el valor de inicio de semana de una fecha dada
 Public lastdayweek As Date 'variable para el valor de la fecha final de una semana de una fecha dada
  

 Friend Property _NSemana As Integer 'indica el numero de la semana 

 Friend Property _iniciosemana As Date 'contiene la primer fecha de la semana dada
  
  'Fuciones para codigo 
  'Funcion para calcular la semana actual en la que estamos
 Function semana() As Date
          _NSemana = (DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, DateTime.Today,                                                           New DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1)) *-1)
 End Function
  
  'esta funcion es la que llamaremos para setear cada valor puedes colocarlo en cualquier evento
  
  Public Sub damerangosemana()
  semana()
  _iniciosemana = RangoSemana((_NSemana + 1), Today.Year)
  firstdayweek = _iniciosemana
  lastdayweek = FinSemana(_iniciosemana)
 End Sub
  
  'con esta funcion capturamos el dia de la semana y asignamos la fecha incial 
  Public Function RangoSemana(ByVal WeekNumber As Integer, ByVal year1 As Integer) As Date
  Dim numdia As Integer = 0
  Dim oneDate As String
  Dim PrimerDia As Date

  oneDate = "1/1/" & year1.ToString
  PrimerDia = DateAndTime.DateValue(oneDate)
  'dayOfYear = inDate.DayOfYear
  Select Case PrimerDia.DayOfWeek
   Case DayOfWeek.Sunday
    numdia = 7
   Case DayOfWeek.Monday
    numdia = 1
   Case DayOfWeek.Tuesday
    numdia = 2
   Case DayOfWeek.Wednesday
    numdia = 3
   Case DayOfWeek.Thursday
    numdia = 4
   Case DayOfWeek.Friday
    numdia = 5
   Case DayOfWeek.Saturday
    numdia = 6
  End Select

  Dim x As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 0 - numdia, CType(oneDate, Date))
  Dim startdate As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, WeekNumber - 1, x)
  Return startdate
 End Function
  
  'funcion para calcular la fecha final
  Public Function FinSemana(ByVal Date1 As Date) As Date
  Return DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 7, Date1)
 End Function
```